# CSS first-of-type applying to all elements

Tags: css, first-of-type

I am trying to use first-of-type to style only the first .menu element in this layout...

```css
.menu:first-of-type
{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <section>
        <div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
<section>
  <div>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</section>
</div>

</div>
```

It is applying the background color to all, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:first-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) targets first child of specific type. As these elements have different parents, the all are first childs. You can prevent this by adding class to `<section>` and using it for that:

```css
.menuSection:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menuSection">
    <div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because :first-of-type makes the rule apply to every element that is first of the type **within its parent element**. You need to capture the first section element and then style the menu element like so:

```
  section:first-of-type .menu
    {
      background:red;
    }
```